# how to traverse through String in java without using ANY BUILT IN Methods?

Tags: java, string

Sorry for the unclear question.Thing is i want to do all operation which can be done on character array(such as retrieving each character in character array,finding spaces between words,finding end of array,etc).In C and C++ i can traverse entire array(character by character)using loop statements.but i am unable to do that in java.To do this i am forced to use toCharArray() method or charAt() method.apart from this is there any other logic?.to be more specific is there any way to convert String to character array,WITHOUT USING ANY(**ANY!!!!**)built in methods(i.e.API)?

Comment: If you can't use any methods, you can't find out _anything_ about the string.  The only way to interact with a string is by calling methods.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this? You can use reflection to read the wrapped `char[]` array...

Comment: Built in methods of the String class or no standard lib methods/classes? Also why?

Comment: I think you are not clear in your requirement

Answer (score 3):

If the only constraint is to not use `charAt()`, then use `toCharArray()`

```
String hello = "Hello dummy, why can't I use charAt";

char[] letters = hello.toCharArray();

// traverse array
```

**Edit: To find space**

```
if (hello[i] == ' ')
```

**Edit: Traversing Strings**

```
character array(such as retrieving each character in character array,finding spaces between words,finding end of array,etc

// traverses through every character in String
for (int i = o; i <hello.length(); i++){
    char c = hello.charAt(i);  
    System.out.println(c); // prints out every char of string

    if (Charcter.isWhiteSpace(hello.charAt(i)){ // checks if char is white space
        // do something
    }

    if (c == ' ') {  // checks if char is whitespace
        // do something
    }
}

// last letter
char c = hello.charAt(hello.length() - 1);
```

You should really look at the `String` java documentation to see all of its available methods. Even check out the `Character` class javadocs

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.Thing is i want to do all operation which can be done on character array(such as retrieving each character in character array,finding spaces between words,finding end of array,etc).In C and C++ i can traverse entire array(character by character)using loop statements.but i am unable to do that in java.To do this i am forced to use toCharArray() method or charAt() method.apart from this is there any other logic?.to be more specific is there any way to convert String to character array,WITHOUT USING ANY(ANY!!!!)built in methods(i.e.API)?

Comment: To answer your question in one word, NO! you can't with out any methods. Why wouldn't you want to use methods though?

Comment: peeskillet ,that was my interviewer requirement.

Comment: @ShyamD Sorry for the necrobump, but I thought I'd just add something. Even in C++, you must use methods. To access a specific char of a `std::string`, you'd need to use a subscript operator (`"Hello"[2]` == `'l'`), but that's a method/function. It's a dumb question because it defeats the purpose of a few important concepts for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can get raw chars of a string using `getBytes()` or `toCharArray()`:

```
String string = "lorem ipsum";
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();

for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
    if(bytes[i] == 0x20){ // ASCII code of space
        System.out.println("Found space at index "+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.Thing is i want to do all operation which can be done on character array(such as retrieving each character in character array,finding spaces between words,finding end of array,etc).In C and C++ i can traverse entire array(character by character)using loop statements.but i am unable to do that in java.To do this i am forced to use toCharArray() method or charAt() method.apart from this is there any other logic?.to be more specific is there any way to convert String to character array,WITHOUT USING ANY(ANY!!!!)built in methods(i.e.API)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. I am assuming you want to find the last character of the string without using the charAt() method.

```
    String example = "I like Java";
    int size = example.length(); //gives the length of the string

    //cuts the string for the last char
    String lastChar = example.subString((size-2), (size-1));
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.Thing is i want to do all operation which can be done on character array(such as retrieving each character in character array,finding spaces between words,finding end of array,etc).In C and C++ i can traverse entire array(character by character)using loop statements.but i am unable to do that in java.To do this i am forced to use toCharArray() method or charAt() method.apart from this is there any other logic?.to be more specific is there any way to convert String to character array,WITHOUT USING ANY(ANY!!!!)built in methods(i.e.API)?